# Closing Form with windows 'X' Button

Tags: c#

My program wasn't exiting when 'X' was clicked so when I looked it up I got this code.

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

but this interferes with the `this.Close()` method.

Is there a way to just use this code when the 'X' is clicked and not when the Form is actually closing? This seems to be the only Form having the problem?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PassMan
{
public partial class Passwords : Form
{
    String[,] UandS = { { "Russell", "Hickey" }, { "Junior", "Russ" } };
    public Passwords()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for (int i = 0; i < UandS.Length / 2; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                if (j % 2 == 0)
                {
                    tbUsernames.Text = tbUsernames.Text + UandS[i, j] + "\r\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    tbPasswords.Text = tbPasswords.Text + UandS[i, j] + "\r\n";
                }
            }
        }
        tbPasswords.PasswordChar = '*';
    }

    private void btnSH_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        if (btnSH.Text == "Show Passwords")
        {
            btnSH.Text = "Hide Passwords";
            tbPasswords.PasswordChar = (char)0;
        }
        else
        {
            btnSH.Text = "Show Passwords";
            tbPasswords.PasswordChar = '*';
        }
    }
    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fLogin main = new fLogin();
        main.Show();
        this.Close();
    }

    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        //Application.Exit();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Can you share some more code?

Comment: It is quite unclear what your problem might be.  Do put it in OnFormClosed() instead to avoid re-entrancy problems.

Comment: Code Updated, for some reason it's only in this form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method receives the FormClosingEventArgs argument. In that argument there is the CloseReason property

The [CloseReason](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.closereason.aspx) property explain why the form is closing....

> A Form can be closed because of a variety of reasons, both
>   user-initiated and programmatic. The CloseReason property indicates a
>   reason for the closure.

You could check this property to see if it is

> **UserClosing** - The user is closing the form through the user interface
>   (UI), for example by clicking the Close button on the form window,
>   selecting Close from the window's control menu, or pressing ALT+F4.
>
> **ApplicationExitCall** - The Exit method of the Application class was
>   invoked.

other reasons for the closing event are explained at the link above

So, if I understand correctly your intentions, you could write

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
       Application.Exit();
    else
       // it is not clear what you want to do in this case .....
}
```